# custom property event input() value not displaying

Tags: angular

> Below is my parent component code. I am trying to get the data from
>   the customebinding component to app component. But i am unable to get
>   the values from the parent component. My parent component is
>   customebinding and child component is appcomponent.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
selector: 'app-customebinding',
templateUrl: './customebinding.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./customebinding.component.scss']
})
export class CustomebindingComponent implements OnInit {
name="ramu";
constructor() { }
ngOnInit() {
}
}
html code is
<app-root [recieveName]="name"></app-root>
```

and below is my child component.

```
    @Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
    })
    export class AppComponent {
    @Input() recieveName:string;
    }
html code is
recieve name is {{ recieveName }}
```

Can any body tell me where is the mistake.

Comment: is there any error in console?

Comment: not getting any error in console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `AppComponent` cannot be you child component if you are bootstrapping your `AppComponent` try to swap the child and parent relationships and bind the `@Input()` property

Hope this helps - Happy coding :)

Comment: Good - happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

App-root component needs to be root as it says. So this should be top level component. Everything goes inside that component and not the other way around.